# Flutter, how to access the State<> object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pointer to a StatefulWidget and I need to read a value in the corresponding State object:

Aa p = Aa();
print(p.count);

How do I do this?

````
```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Aa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AaState createState() => _AaState();
}

class _AaState extends State<Aa> {
  int count;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
````

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think what you really want is to pass the value of the variable through to the other widget that wants to "read" from this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GlobalKey. You can't access State directly from Widget because multiple states could be associated with the same widget.

Answer (score 0):

A reference of a StatefulWidget is not enough to obtain its associated state, for a simple reason:

A StatefulWidget can be associated to more than just one State.

So what you're asking is simplh impossible.

On the other hand, you can use GlobalKey or BuildContext to obtain a State.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the state of the widget and then access

```
class MySFWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SFWidgetState currState;

  @override
  SFWidgetState createState(){
    currState = new SFWidgetState();
    return currState;
  };

}

class SFWidgetState extends State<MySFWidget> {

  int count;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then, access its property by :

`myWidgetInstance.currState.count`